# Fails to call a plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

im trying to develop a plugin that render a datagrid to html element. For example in:

```
<div id="datagrid">
    <!-- Renderizado via Backbone.js -->
</div>
```

I have this plugin definition:

```
// csDatagrid.js
(function($) {
    $.fn.csDatagrid = function(options) {
       // Code ...
    };
}, (jQuery));
```

And i call the function in this way:

```
// csAuditarSesiones.js
$("#datagrid").csDatagrid({
    columns: cols,
    url: $("#sfAction").val(),
    filterBy: 'user_str'
});
```

Chrome says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'csDatagrid'

Load library queue (Chrome Developer Tools):

1. JQuery
2. csDatagrid (my plugin)
3. csAuditarSesiones (script with code for the current page, have the plugin call)

Thanks !

**EDIT 1**

Apparently the plugin not load, follow code always print "Not Loaded !":

```
if(jQuery().csDatagrid) {
    console.log("Loaded !");
}else{
    console.log("Not Loaded !");
}
```

Comment: I follow the steps detaileds in this [link](http://www.queness.com/post/112/a-really-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial). This, work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason here is you are defining your plugin in the document ready event. Therefore the elements calling this plugin must call the plugin after the plugin has been loaded.

Try defining your new plugin outside of a load\ready event such as.

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.csDatagrid = function(options) {
           // Code ...
        };
    }, (jQuery));

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#datagrid").csDatagrid({
    columns: cols,
    url: $("#sfAction").val(),
    filterBy: 'user_str'
});
```

});

Just for refrence (surely reading it now). http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

***EDIT***:

Is it possible you have multiple jQuery versions being loaded? This can happen when there are conflicts. Also ensure that your plugin is loaded after the javascript file and before the document ready function.

There is one other (i have no idea why I believe it is when multiple versions are loaded) phenomenom that happens and you have to add the $ call back to your ready function. Such as.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
   //TODO: Code here
});
```

Comment: I read the doc, but i havent claer if write the plugin inside of the ready listener. So, change those lines, but the plugin still not working. The plugin are defined in another file, this is important ?

Comment: No, im load only one JQuery version.

Answer (score 0):

#### There is error in your immediate invoked function's last line.

}, (jQuery)); should be :

})(jQuery);